# Tumble theme: styling "single post" view

Tags: wordpress, tumblr

For my blog index, I use small-ish images (250px wide). 
If I view a single post, I'd like it to be bigger (e.g. 500px wide).

Is this possible? I can only see one block that applies to all posts.

I guess I'm looking for the WordPress-equivalent of `single.php`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two tumblr tags that you might find useful:

```
{block:Posts}{/block:Posts}
```

and

```
{block:PermalinkPage} {/block:PermalinkPage}
```

The first set is the regular way of displaying your posts, where as the second set of tags targets "single" pages only. What I would do, if I was looking to change views between the index page and the single page, I'd wrap one set inside another, like this:

```
{block:Posts}
//Normal posts as displayed on the home page
{/block:Posts}

{block:PermalinkPage}
 {block:Posts}
  //Targets posts when displayed in "single" view...
 {/block:Posts}
{/block:PermalinkPage}
```

Hope this helps & works :)